# How to customize the Spinner dropdown view

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

Is it  possible to customize the spinner drop-down view . Default spinner drop-down view has adapter view . I want change that view to have my own text view or some thing like this.

Comment: see this I hope this help u http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

Comment: Are you using CustomAdapter or ArrayAdapter?

Comment: You actually put your customization in the adapter.  It has methods getView and getDropDownView and getDropDownView which return a view.  In these methods you create and init your text view and return it.

Answer (score 7):

Add this inner class in your class and modify it as you please.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.xml.row, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
            label.setText(strings[position]);

            TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
            sub.setText(subs[position]);

            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

            return row;
            }
        }
```

And add this adapter to your spinner:

```
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.expandableImagesList);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(NewEventActivity.this, R.xml.row, strings));
```

And also create a new xml and add all the things you want your spinner to contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="3dip"
>
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <TextView
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
         android:padding="3dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:id="@+id/company"
         android:text="CoderzHeaven"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
         android:padding="2dip"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:id="@+id/sub"
         android:layout_below="@+id/company"
         android:text="Heaven of all working codes"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code so you have to change it for your needs

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the drop-down view by overriding `getDropDownView` method from your `ArrayAdapter`.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
     ...
}
```

Comment: @waqasalam Can you post any example code to understand ,how it is  working?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.your_layout);
```

where `your_layout` is your XML containing only a `TextView`