# How to get Spinner dropdown view to draw on it or the view of one of the items in the dropdown?

Tags: android, view, android-spinner, dropdown

I have a need from the product team to get the instance of the currently open `Spinner` dropdown view and alter it or present a `Showcase` above one of it's dropdown items. After going over some questions here and other articles like this one:

[Android Spinner - How to make dropdown view transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918468/android-spinner-how-to-make-dropdown-view-transparent)

and this one:

[How to customize the Spinner dropdown view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990046/how-to-customize-the-spinner-dropdown-view)

I'm getting the feeling that the only access I have to the dropdown is using the xml parameters or the `Spinner` adapter. Yet I decided to ask the question anyway to relax my superior.

Another thing that might be helpful in my case is to get notified when the `Spinner` is expended, and find the opened popup instance as a result of this notification, but following this question:

[Spinner: get state or get notified when opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens)

It looks like this is also can't be done without extending the Spinner into a custom view, something that in my case is not possible, as I need to do it from the SDK side that I'm writing for use on a standard `Spinner`.

Has any one here dealt with a `Spinner` and managed to get the view instance of the dropdown or even better the view instance of one of the dropdown items? I would be grateful if you can direct me in the right direction on how this can be achieved?

**UPDATE:** I have managed to get the view hierarchy of the spinner dropdown using the following code:

```
//Function to get all available windows of the application using reflection
private void logRootViews() {
    try {
        Class wmgClass = Class.forName("android.view.WindowManagerGlobal");
        Object wmgInstnace = wmgClass.getMethod("getInstance").invoke(null, (Object[])null);

        Method getViewRootNames = wmgClass.getMethod("getViewRootNames");
        Method getRootView = wmgClass.getMethod("getRootView", String.class);
        String[] rootViewNames = (String[])getViewRootNames.invoke(wmgInstnace, (Object[])null);

        for(String viewName : rootViewNames) {
            View rootView = (View)getRootView.invoke(wmgInstnace, viewName);
            Log.i(TAG, "Found root view: " + viewName + ": " + rootView);
            getViewHierarchy(rootView);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Functions to get hierarchy
private void getViewHierarchy(View view) {
    //This is how I start recursion to get view hierarchy
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
        dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(group, 0);
    } else {
        dumpViewWithProperties(view, 0);
    }
}

private void dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(ViewGroup group, int level) {
    if (!dumpViewWithProperties(group, level)) {
        return;
    }

    final int count = group.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View view = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties((ViewGroup) view, level + 1);
        } else {
            dumpViewWithProperties(view, level + 1);
        }
    }
}

private boolean dumpViewWithProperties(View view, int level) {
    //Add to view Hierarchy.
    if (view instanceof TextView) {
        Log.d(TAG, "TextView from hierarchy dumped: " + view.toString() + " with text: " + ((TextView) view).getText().toString() + " ,in Level: " + level);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "View from hierarchy dumped: " + view.toString() + " ,in Level: " + level);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that to get all the decor windows of the application I need to use reflection, which is something I can't do in the SDK I'm writing, more over as I understand I use here a private API which can be changed at any moment and as I understood Google blocks applications from the store which do use a private API.

**So the updated question is:** Is there a way to do the same operation without reflection and private API?